# I would like to find a laptop for general purpose use and a little gaming

Tags: laptop

I don't know if this is the place to ask this but I'll try anyway. Asking for a friend so I won't be able to provide all the information.

They want a general purpose laptop to use for school and a little bit of gaming. The gaming won't be high end at all so it doesn't need to be super powerful or anything. A few requirements are below.

Windows 10
8 GB of RAM
512 GB Memory
$500 - 600

If any other information is needed ask and I'll try to find out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Acer Aspire E15 at  $599.99

- Intel Core i5-8250U 1.6 GHz
- Ram - 8GB DDR4
- NVIDIA GeForce MX150
- Storage - 256GB SSD
- 15.6” FHD IPS (1920 x 1080)
- Battery Life - 15 hours
- Windows 10 Home

*** 256GB SSD is far more faster than 500GB HDD ***

- You can visit the link given below to buy or see the specifications

[https://www.amazon.com/dp/B075FLBJV7?creativeASIN=B075FLBJV7&linkCode=w61&imprToken=G5aW3AJR5gr.83YRFgeJIw&slotNum=5&tag=bestlaptopsworld-20](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B075FLBJV7)